# How to build multiple boxplots for 4 variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

I need help creating a multi box plot for my data frame.

data = Example_document

Attribute(Variable) = F1, F2, F3, F4, F5

Can someone please explain how I can achieve this and get a graph like below?

[image]

DATA file name: TestData

$ KF1     : num
$ KF3     : num
$ KF4     : num
$ KF5     : num
$ KF6     : num
$ KF7     : num
$ KF8     : num
$ KF9     : num
$ KF10    : num

'''

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

maybe first using the funtion "melt" from the "reshape2" library.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# 1. I dont have your data so i created this fake one:
Your_Data <- data.frame(
  "station" = seq(1:100),
  "Month_1" = rnorm(100,25,25),
  "Month_2" = rnorm(100,30,25),
  "Month_3" = rnorm(100,35,25),
  "Month_4" = rnorm(100,12,25))

# 2. Then you could transform it into a panel using "melt":
Your_Data <- reshape2::melt(
  Your_Data,
  id.vars = "station",
  variable.name = "Month",
  value.name = "Ozone")

# 3. The plot should be something like this
ggplot(Your_Data, aes(Month, Ozone)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  # To set labels on the plot
  labs(
      title = "Boxplot of mean ozone by month",
      x = "Month",
      y = "Means ozone in \nparts per billion") +
  # To center the plot's title 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]